# How merge two columns into one column in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Basically, I have two columns that I want to merge together with certain rules. Using the following code, I built a similar dataframe.

```
primaryColumn = pd.Series(["Orange", np.nan, np.nan, "Cyan"])
secondaryColumn = pd.Series(["Red", "Green", np.nan, "Blue"])

pd.concat([secondaryColumn, primaryColumn], axis=1)
```

[image]

I basically want to keep whatever is in column 1, bring over whatever is in column 0 to replace any nan values, and then keep any nan values that are in both columns. It should result in a column with these values:

0    Orange
1     Green
2       NaN
3      Cyan

I've tried merge and concat, but of course most functions are for putting dataframes together, not columns.

Answer (score 2):

This is more like `fillna`

```
s=primaryColumn.fillna(secondaryColumn)
s
0    Orange
1     Green
2       NaN
3      Cyan
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

try this...

```
df.loc[df['1'].isnull(),'1'] = df['0']
```

Answer (score 0):

[fill forward](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html) on the columns axis

```
df.ffill(axis=1)

     0        1
0   Red     Orange
1   Green   Green
2    NaN    NaN
3   Blue    Cyan
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume that you have concatenated your 2 source *Series* into
a DataFrame and you have:

```
       0       1
0    Red  Orange
1  Green     NaN
2    NaN     NaN
3   Blue    Cyan
```

To generate the third column, define a function getting the
last valid value from a row or *NaN*:

```
def lastValid(row):
    ind = row[::-1].first_valid_index()
    return row[ind] if pd.notnull(ind) else np.nan
```

Then apply this function, saving the result in a new column:

```
df[2] = df.apply(lastValid, axis=1)
```

The result is:

```
       0       1       2
0    Red  Orange  Orange
1  Green     NaN   Green
2    NaN     NaN     NaN
3   Blue    Cyan    Cyan
```

Or if you want to overwrite *1* column, instead of creating new column,
change *2* to *1*.

It works also when you have more source columns, the only detail to
take the proper name of the output column.